# Haskell read lines of file

Tags: file, haskell, io

I want to read a whole file into a string and then use the function `lines` to get the lines of the string. I'm trying to do it with these lines of code:

```
main = do
   args <- getArgs
   content <- readFile (args !! 0)
   linesOfFiles <- lines content
```

But I'm getting the following error by compiling ad it fails:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO t0' with actual type `[String]'
In the return type of a call of `lines'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: linesOfFiles <- lines content
```

I thought by binding the result of `readFile` to content it will be a `String` DataType, why isn't it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> I thought by binding the result of readFile to content it will be a String DataType, why isn't it?

It is a `String` indeed, that's not what the compiler complains about. Let's look at the code:

```
main = do
   args <- getArgs
   content <- readFile (args !! 0)
```

Now `content` is, as desired, a plain `String`. And then `lines content` is a `[String]`. But you're using the monadic binding in the next line

```
   linesOfFiles <- lines content
```

in an `IO ()` do-block. So the compiler expects an expression of type `IO something` on the right hand side of the `<-`, but it finds a `[String]`.

Since the computation `lines content` doesn't involve any `IO`, you should bind its result with a `let` binding instead of the monadic binding,

```
   let linesOfFiles = lines content
```

is the line you need there.

Comment: Additionally, compare this to the type of getArgs and readFile, for completeness.

Comment: How does this solution work? You can't pass `content` to `lines` because the type of `lines` is `String -> [String]` and the type of `content` is `IO String`

Comment: @kjh No, `content` is a `String`. The type of `readFile (args !! 0)` is `IO String`, and we bind `content` to the "result" of that `IO`-action. The construct `do { a <- action; stuff; }` desugars into `action >>= \a -> stuff`, if `action` has type `IO t`, then `a` has type `t`.

Comment: I see now. Thank you for clarifying